# PHP Dynamic Function Variables?

Tags: php

So in the base PHP Functions (probably not a good reference but anyway) example, the function `array_push($arr, $info)` - you can put as many items in the `$info` variable as you want, but example if you don't put in a paramater in a function that you made, example `public function __connstruct($conn_string, $drivers)`, how would one want to achieve making the `$drivers` variable not needed unless the function is called with it.

Is it a special type of variable in the function?

Comment: [default argument values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)?!

Comment: refer the function func_get_args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: default arguments

```
public function __construct($conn_string, $drivers = null)
{
  // do something
}
```

This makes $drivers an optional function argument

Comment: Thanks so much, I feel so stupid now but thanks for answering anyway :)